# An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm new to php and symphony. I'm trying to install some php package using composer. I'm getting this error:

> Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>   handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
>
> [RuntimeException]   An error occurred when executing the
>   ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command:
>
> ```
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>
> Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
> ```
>
> date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this wa
>   rn
>       ing, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to
>   select your timezone.

Some idea about what can cause this?

Comment: You haven't set a default time zone in php.ini - remember there's usually a php.ini for your web server and another one for php cli

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because the php.ini does not have defined the default timezone. To make the changes server independent you can easily solve that issue by adding the following code to the `AppKernel` class inside `AppKernel.php`:

```
public function __construct($environment, $debug)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
    }
```

Where `Europe/Berlin` is your timezone. Once done that before issuing any command you have to load your page at least once so the AppKernel class constructor is run at least once. Afterwards you can run the proper command and it should work properly.